# Create animation in imageviews

Tags: android, image, animation, imageview

I have an imageview with a default image. Now when I try to click it, I want it to animate that displays 4 frames of images. How could I accomplish this, I tried a simpler approach (more of a dumb approach) by changing the imageresource 4 times, as expected the image changes so fast that the animating image effect is not visible. Any ideas?

I tried this approach:

```
Gem = (ImageView)v;
    Gem.setImageResource(com.example.gems.R.drawable.bd1);
    Gem.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Gem.setImageResource(com.example.gems.R.drawable.bd2);
            Gem.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Gem.setImageResource(com.example.gems.R.drawable.bd3);
                    Gem.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Gem.setImageResource(com.example.gems.R.drawable.bd4);
                            Gem.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                }
                            }, 500);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }, 500);
```

It worked, but is there a better way to this without coding too much lines? I have 25 kinds of images and each image has 4 frames.

EDIT:

I tried using xml transition files:

Java file:

```
Resources res = this.getResources();
    Gem = (ImageView)v;
    TransitionDrawable transition;

    transition = (TransitionDrawable)
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_diamond_animation);
    Gem.setImageDrawable(transition);
    transition.startTransition(3000);
```

xml file:

```
 <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bd1"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bd2"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bd3"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bd4"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/invi"></item>
 </transition>
```

This seems to work, but I don't want to draw this images in a transition. I want to change the background in a transition. I tried changing this `android:drawable` to `android:drawable` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there is an exact class for this: [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Basically, just add frames with the other pictures to use in the animation to the `AnimationDrawable` object and specify how long they should display using `addFrame(Drawable frame, int duration)`

Then set the `ImageView` to display whatever image it should start with and set the background to the `AnimationDrawable` you just made using `setBackgroundDrawable(Animation)`

Lastly, start the animation in the `onClick` listener

**EDIT: FOR EXAMPLE**

```
AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
ad.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1), 100);
ad.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2), 500);
ad.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image3), 300);

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
```

And then in your onClick listener, just call `ad.start`

Comment: Can you give an example code or pseudocode in this? I don't quite get it.

Comment: I used animation drawable, made it work. How can I stop the animation? I mean I just want it to display 5 frames then stop at the last frame.

Comment: You should use the method `ad.setOneShot(true)` this should make it only play once through.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. You have not given enough info to go on

The viewproperty animator is really the easiest thing to use have a look. It can also be used with older API's using nineoldandroids jar (google it)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html

The ObjectAnimator and ValueAnimator are also available similar and slightly more difficult to implement

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html

Have a look at the APIdemos in the sample packs there are a few examples mainly using the ValueAnimator.
http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

There are also Sprites  to consider but it is basically a bitmap , you can user the timer obect to  choreograph

Comment: I tried using the transition xml. It worked but I want to change the background image in a transition, not draw on top of my existing view. Any ideas?